# How can I select one Radio Button in adapter class without Radio Group

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

**RecyclerView Adapter Class**

```
package com.ajitapp.smartwork.adapters;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.ajitapp.smartwork.ChooseAddressActivity;
import com.ajitapp.smartwork.Interfaces.AddressClickListener;
import com.ajitapp.smartwork.Interfaces.CartClickListListener;
import com.ajitapp.smartwork.R;
import com.ajitapp.smartwork.models.AddressModal;
import com.ajitapp.smartwork.models.CartModel;

import java.util.List;

public class AddressListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AddressListAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private List<AddressModal> arrayList;
    private Context context;
    private AddressClickListener cartClickListListener;
    public int mSelectedItem = -1;

    private RadioButton lastCheckedRB = null;


    public AddressListAdapter(Context applicationContext, List<AddressModal> arrayList, ChooseAddressActivity cartClickListListener) {
        this.arrayList = arrayList;
        this.context = applicationContext;
        this.cartClickListListener = cartClickListListener;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public AddressListAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.choose_address_row_item, parent, false);
        context = parent.getContext(); //to get the activity context use this line.

        final AddressListAdapter.MyViewHolder myViewHolder = new AddressListAdapter.MyViewHolder(view);
        return myViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull AddressListAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        holder.addr1.setText(arrayList.get(position).getAddr1());
        holder.addr2.setText(arrayList.get(position).getAddr2());
        holder.city.setText(arrayList.get(position).getCity());
        holder.state.setText(arrayList.get(position).getCity());
        holder.country.setText(arrayList.get(position).getCountry());
        holder.postalCode.setText(arrayList.get(position).getPostalCode());


        holder.radioButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                mSelectedItem=position;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return arrayList.size();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView addr1, addr2, city, state, country, postalCode;
        private TextView subtask_description_tv;
        private TextView subtask_price_tv;
        private Button incrementBtn, decrementBtn;
        private TextView display_data;
        private TextView total_price_tv;

        private RadioButton radioButton;

        int total_price;

        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            addr1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.addr1);
            addr2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.addr2);
            city = itemView.findViewById(R.id.city);
            state = itemView.findViewById(R.id.state);
            country = itemView.findViewById(R.id.country);
            postalCode = itemView.findViewById(R.id.postalCode);

            radioButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.addressRadioButton);




        }


    }
}
```

***Item Row***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_address_list"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
        app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_arrow_back"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Choose an address"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            />
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/locationImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:src="@drawable/address"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar_address_list"
        />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_add"
        android:id="@+id/add_address"
        android:text="Add new address"
        android:layout_below="@id/locationImage"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:drawablePadding="5dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/add_address"
        android:id="@+id/address_list" />



    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buy_btn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:text="Continue"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_arrow_forward"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:elevation="10dp"

        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I want to click one Radio Button in Recycler View, but I failed to do that. I have tried all the possibilities, but I failed to try from everywhere. I want to click one Radio Button in Recycler View, but I failed to do that. I have tried all the possibilities, but I failed to try from everywhere.

Comment: Row --- **** ---

Answer (score 0):

First you need condition like this for your UI in your onBindViewHolder method

```
if (mSelectedItem == position) {
        holder.radioButton.setChecked(true);
    } else {
        holder.radioButton.setChecked(false);
    }
```

Then change your radio button listener like this

```
holder.radioButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                mSelectedItem = position;
            } else {
                mSelectedItem = -1;
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

try this i hope your problem will solve.